# How to apply patch on postgresql 9.2

Tags: postgresql-9.2

Hi all I would like to apply one patch(pg_dump_grouplock.patch) in my PostgreSQL 9.2 database 
regarding lock table issue advised on below link

http://www.postgresql-archive.org/pg-dump-and-thousands-of-schemas-td5709766i40.html

I have never applied the patch, can anybody let me know the step how to apply the patch.

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.2 is out of support (no longer maintained). You should plan an upgrade to 9.6 or 10.0 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Instead update to PostgreSQL 9.2.23, which includes a better fix.

---

If you really must patch it: clone PostgreSQL's source code from git, check out 9.2, apply patch, compile.

```
git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/postgresql.git
cd postgresql
git checkout REL9_2_STABLE
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/pg_dump_grouplock.patch
./configure ...
```

See [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/installation.html) for compile instructions.

Comment: Thanks Craig Ringer,, i can apply patch on my test server but due to some security issue , i can not do git clone on my prod DB ,could you please let me know how to patch existing  server

Comment: You must compile from source code. You cannot apply a patch to a binary install. Get a tarball instead if you can't clone from git. See the PostgreSQL download page. But... really. Just don't do this. Simply apply the PostgreSQL 9.2.23 update.

Comment: thanks Craig, Actully i am doing this because my db has more than 1000K relation , and when i am upgrading it to 9.6 its stuck at pg_dump location even i am using --link option . thought that might make the pg_dump faster  do you have any solution, to upgrade faster with db 1000K relation

Comment: Yes, I do. Upgrade to 9.2.23 first. It's a simple in-place upgrade, install new binaries and restat. Then upgrading to 9.6 will be faster. I've said this enough times now, so I won't be repeating myself further.

Comment: my current version ispostgres=# select version();
                                                   version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=#

Comment: **so upgrade**!

Comment: Thanks, Craig, I am able to upgrade the DB in 1.5 hours.

Comment: i got below error during upgrade .

Comment: If pg_upgrade fails after this point, you must re-initdb the
new cluster before continuing.

Performing Upgrade
------------------
Analyzing all rows in the new cluster                       "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/vacuumdb" --host '/var/lib/pgsql' --port 50432 --username 'postgres' --all --analyze --verbose >> "pg_upgrade_utility.log" 2>&1

*failure*
There were problems executing ""/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/vacuumdb" --host '/var/lib/pgsql' --port 50432 --username 'postgres' --all --analyze --verbose >> "pg_upgrade_utility.log" 2>&1"

Comment: Consult the last few lines of "pg_upgrade_utility.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.
Failure, exiting
"/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/pg_ctl" -w -D "/postgresql/9.6/data/" -o "" -m fast stop >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1

Comment: Um, that's nice? Post a new question with proper details, after you *do what the error message says*. It tells you where to look.